# Serverless Lambda monorepo project deploy only changed files custom CI file

Tags: aws-lambda, gitlab-ci, serverless-framework, serverless

We develop a project all RestApi services is a Lambda function, We use serverless framework for AWS Lambda deploying. Project is mono-repo.

It's folder structure like this

```
./app (this is shared folder and a layer on AWS )
  - /Models
  - /Helper
  - ...
./services
  - /ServiceGroup
    - /service1
      - service.handler
      - config.yml
    - /service2
      - service.handler
      - config.yml
  - /AnotherServiceGroup
    - /service3
        - service.handler
        - config.yml
      - /service4
        - service.handler
        - config.yml
- serverless.yml (this yml configuration file is including all services configuration files)
```

We use custom own gitlab server. And this project CI folder run this code for lambda deploy

```
serverless deploy
```

This command deploy all services but we want deploy only changed services. How to customize CI for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your services share the same `serverless.yml` file, they live in the same cloudformation stack, so what you're asking for doesn't work.

You can use `serverless deploy function` to update just one function, but that skips cloudformation, so new resources won't be created and your stack will drift. You should use it during development, but not for production deployments.

I strongly recommend [splitting your stacks](https://dev.to/aws-builders/serverless-at-team-scale-a8). You can still use a mono-repo, and then you can conditionally deploy services depending on which files changed for a given commit.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer :) Today i had a serverless error. 

The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 504, is greater than maximum allowed, 500.

I will split project stacks. I think nested stacks logical groups for example (Authentication, User, etc.) Already, service group name of definations like that.